# How to obtain trend from a table for the same column values in multiple row that needs group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm facing few issues in getting the trend by grouping when trend is calculated from the me same column keying different rows. Can someone please help me? Input and output tables are below.

```
Input:
Name    Interval    Count
A       Last        100
A       First       200
B       Last        200
B       First       100
C       Last        100
C       First       100
D       Last        100
E       First       10

Output:
Name    LastCount   Trend-- ((First-Last)/First)*100)
A       100         50 %
B       200        -100%
C       100         0%
D       100         NULL-- No value exists and consider as 0. Divide By 0 as NULL
E       0           100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Name, A.LastCount, (((A.FirstCount-A.LastCount)/A.FirstCount)*100) Trend
FROM (SELECT A.Name, MAX(IF(A.Interval = 'Last', A.Count, 0)) LastCount, 
             MAX(IF(A.Interval = 'First', A.Count, 0)) FirstCount
      FROM tableA A
      GROUP BY A.Name
     ) AS A
```

Comment: Thank you and it worked!
Here is SQL Fiddler link, [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1124/14